# Form element which is cannot be edited by "view source"

Tags: html

There is a register form on the page. I want to record the user IP and register the date so I change those input type "hidden" but user can change those value from view source. How can I prevent that from happening?

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">                  
    <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name..."><br>
    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
    <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
    <input class="form-control" name="cPassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password..."><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="registerip" value="<?php echo $ip_address ?>" >
    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="registerdate" value="<?php echo $currentDateTime ?>" >
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: You **cannot** prevent the user from doing that. Why not record the users ip address and the current time on the register.php page?

Comment: Hmm its sad.But i dont know another way to do that.And cant imagine...

Comment: What do you mean you don't know another way? How are you setting that `$ip_Address` variable....??

Comment: I mean how can i caught the data without input..

Comment: `caught the data without input..` I don't know what this means, but you should be able to figure out how to add the `$ip_address` variable to your `register.php` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If it's in the HTML, then it's on the user's computer and they can do whatever they want.

You need to do this server-side, in your 'register.php' file. When you collect the submitted values there, just add `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for the IP address and something like `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` for the date.

Comment: Hmm yeah its logical...lets try

Comment: No problem. Could you mark the answer as accepted then? Also keep in mind that if you're doing this for security, it's not difficult for someone to change their IP address. They can just use a VPN or TOR to change it around.